# Ocultar campo de ModelForm de acuerdo al perfil del usuario usando UpdateView - Django

Tags: django

Tengo un formulario de solicitudes que posee dos campos (nombreMail y estado). Pero quiero que cuando el usuario tenga un perfil distinto a "informatica" oculte el campo estado para que no pueda ser cambiado por éste.

Lo que estuve intentando hacer, pero aún no conseguí que funcione ya que me arroja el error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'`, es sobreescribir el método `__init__()` de `SolicitudForm` en forms.py y por otro lado, sobreescribir el método `get_form_kwargs()` para poder pasarle el usuario del request al form de solicitud. Les dejo el código que entiendo relevante:

**views.py:**

```
...
class SolicitudUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Solicitud
form_class = SolicitudForm
template_name = 'solicitud/solicitud_form.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('solicitud:solicitud_listar')

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SolicitudForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitud
        fields = [
            'nombreMail',
            'estado',
        ]
        labels = {
            'nombreMail': 'Nombre de la casilla de correo incluyendo @dominio.ejemplo',
            'estado': 'Estado de la solicitud:'
        }
        widgets = {
            'nombreMail': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.user.is_informatica == False:
                self.fields.pop('estado')
```

**models.py**

```
...
class Solicitud(models.Model):
   nombreMail = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   estados = [('1','Pendiente'), ('2','En proceso'), ('3','Realizada')]
   estado = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=estados, default='1')
   user = models.ManyToManyField(Solicitante, blank=True)
```

¿por qué se produce el error de *unexpected keyword argument 'user'*? ¿qué sugerencias me podrían hacer para ocultar ese campo de acuerdo al perfil?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba sobrescribir el metodo **init** del formulario SolicitudForm de la siguiente forma:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # establece user como un atributo del formulario
            self.user = user
            if self.user.is_informatica == False:
                self.fields.pop('estado')
```

Con eso no deberia darte el error de *unexpected keyword argument 'user'*